# Regression scoring decreases with Gridsearch

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

I am new to scikit learn so please excuse my ignorance. Using GridsearchCV I am trying to optimize a DecisionTreeRegressor. The broader I make the parameter space, the worse the scoring gets.

Setting min_samples_split to range(2,10) gives me a neg_mean_squared_error of -0.04. When setting it to range(2,5) The score is -0.004.

```
simple_tree =GridSearchCV(tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42), n_jobs=4, param_grid={'min_samples_split': range(2, 10)}, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=10, refit='neg_mean_squared_error')

simple_tree.fit(x_tr,y_tr).score(x_tr,y_tr)
```

I expect an equal or more positive score for a more extensive grid search compared to the less extensive one.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you should have a metric that gets closer to 0 when having more parameters.. if you were really comparing the ***same*** model each time. This is not the case in the code you provided, because you have not set the `random_state` parameter in your Decision Tree.

Do `DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 42)` (or any integer) and you should have more sensible results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I understand that fixing the random state will allow for code reproducibility. Could you please explain when not to use a fixed random_state?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve it. With setting random_state=42 I get -0.004 vs -0.04

Comment: Are you resplitting X_train for both attempts?

Comment: As to your first question, you need to be careful not to overuse random_state. I would advise only to use it when you want to ensure reproducibility like in this example

Comment: You mean resplitting by setting CV=10? Yes I am.

Comment: No, I meant are you rerunning train_test_split or anything similar between the two evaluations? In other words, is x_tr the exact same each time?

Answer (score 0):

Using simple_tree.best_score_ gives the mean best score over all CV folds.